# Pandas to_dict data structure, using column as dictionary index

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

This is just a very specific data structure transformation that I'm trying to achieve with pandas, so if you know how to do it, please share :)

Imagine I have a dataframe that looks like this

| id | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-04-01 |
| 1 | 5 | 2021-04-02 |
| 1 | 10 | 2021-04-03 |
| 2 | 3 | 2021-04-01 |
| 2 | 4 | 2021-04-02 |
| 2 | 11 | 2021-04-03 |

Now I want to transform this into an object, where the keys are the ids, and the values are arrays of information about that id. So it would look like this...

```
{
  '1': [
         { 'value': 1, 'date': '2021-04-01' },
         { 'value': 5, 'date': '2021-04-02' },
         { 'value': 10, 'date': '2021-04-03' }
       ],
  '2': [
         { 'value': 3, 'date': '2021-04-01' },
         { 'value': 4, 'date': '2021-04-02' },
         { 'value': 11, 'date': '2021-04-03' }
       ],
}
```

I imagine I have to use `.to_dict()` somehow, but I can't quite figure out how to do it?

Thoughts?

Edit: I've already figured out a brute-force way of doing it, I'm looking for something more elegant ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby()` on `id` and then `apply()` `to_dict()` on each group:

```py
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x[['value', 'date']].to_dict(orient='records')).to_dict()
```

```
{1: [{'value': 1, 'date': '2021-04-01'}, {'value': 5, 'date': '2021-04-02'}, {'value': 10, 'date': '2021-04-03'}], 2: [{'value': 3, 'date': '2021-04-01'}, {'value': 4, 'date': '2021-04-02'}, {'value': 11, 'date': '2021-04-03'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension after converting the dataframe to dict object.

But here's a more Pandas-way,if your `id` column is a real column of the dataframe,

```py
df = df.set_index('id').T.to_dict()
```

If you meant `id` as the index of dataframe, just use,

```py
df = df.T.to_dict()
```

Comment: this doesn't produce what I'm looking for, and i get a warning

Comment: That is because the id is not a column, but just indices. Use the second method I added to answer.

Comment: it still doesn't give me the answer i was looking for